# How do I open a file from a folder in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, replit

I am using Bash on repl.it. I am making my own command line, and I would like to know how to run a script from a folder called commands. Basically, I would like to make a file run from a folder. How can I do this?

[image: A picture describing what I want to do]

[Link to my repl](https://repl.it/@Gem1n1531/Terminal)

Comment: Ohh if this does help i am an Explorer on repl.it (basically means that I have experimental features on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just run it like this?

```
sh commands/${input}.sh
```

Also you should be able to push/pop dir to go into/out of directories.

```
pushd commands
# adds cwd into a stack and goes to <dir> commands/
sh $input.sh
popd 
# goes back to last dir in stack.
```

Comment: any more advice?

Comment: ok it worked BUT my error messenger (AKA the if statement above) keeps f-ing it up lol